# quanto adjustments

Tags: derivatives, numerairechange

Here is `quanto adjustments` in John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  9th` `page 699.`

[image]

I know that we have
$$E_X[V] = E_Y[VW].$$
And, $V$ and $W$ should be both martingale under $Y$-measure, so we simply write
$$\dfrac{dV}{V} = \sigma_V d W_V$$
$$\dfrac{dW}{W} = \sigma_W  d W_W$$
$$d W_Vd W_W = \rho d t$$
But how can we obtain the final result in the book
$$E_X[V] = E_Y[V]e^{\rho \sigma_V\sigma_W T}.$$
It seems not the same result as two log-normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the dynamics for $V$, under $Y$, is not the form you provided. In particular, a measure change will change the drift of $V$. 
Specifically, the dynamics of $V$ is typically of the form 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{V} = -\sigma_V\sigma_W \rho dt + \sigma_V d W_V.
\end{align*}
You can now check that the final result holds.

> Addendum

We assume that, under $X$, $V$ satisfies an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{V} = \sigma_V d \widetilde{W}_V.
\end{align*}
Moreover, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\eta = \frac{dY}{dX}$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\eta}{\eta} = \sigma_W d \widetilde{W}_W,
\end{align*}
where $d\langle \widetilde{W}_V, \widetilde{W}_W\rangle = \tilde{\rho} dt$. Then, by Cholesky decomposition,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\eta}{\eta} = \sigma_W d \left(\tilde{\rho}\widetilde{W}_V+ \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} \widetilde{B}_W\right).
\end{align*}
where $\widetilde{W}_V$ and $\widetilde{B}_W$ are two independent standard Brownian motions.
Moreover, by Girsanov transformation,
\begin{align*}
W_V &= \widetilde{W}_V - \sigma_W \tilde{\rho} t\, \mbox{ and}\\
B_W &= \widetilde{B}_W - \sigma_W \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} t
\end{align*} 
are two standard Brownian motions under $Y$. Let $W= \eta^{-1} = \left(\frac{dY}{dX}\right)^{-1}$. Then, under $Y$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{V} &= \sigma_V\sigma_W\tilde{\rho} dt +\sigma_V d W_V,\\
\frac{dW}{W} &=\eta d\left(\frac{1}{\eta}\right)\\
&= -\frac{d\eta}{\eta}+\frac{1}{\eta^2} d\langle \eta,\eta\rangle\\
&=\sigma_W^2 dt -\sigma_W d \left(\tilde{\rho}\widetilde{W}_V+ \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} \widetilde{B}_W\right)\\
&=-\sigma_W d \left(\tilde{\rho}W_V+ \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} B_W\right).
\end{align*}
Let $\rho=-\tilde{\rho}$ and $W_W=\tilde{\rho}W_V+ \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} B_W$. Then, under $Y$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{V} &= -\sigma_V\sigma_W\rho dt +\sigma_V d W_V,\\
\frac{dW}{W} &=\sigma_W d W_W,
\end{align*} 
where $d\langle W_V, W_W\rangle_t = \rho dt.$ Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
E_X(V) &= E_Y\left(\frac{dX}{dY} V \right)\\
&=E_Y\left(\left(\frac{dY}{dX}\right)^{-1} V \right)\\
&=E_Y(VW).
\end{align*}

Comment: but if $V$ is not martingale under $Y,$  then it doesn't make sense?

Comment: $V$ does not have to be martingale. The purpose of measure change is to make the computation feasible, rather than to make the quantity (e.g., the payoff of an option) a martingale, though $W$ should be a martingale, and the discounted value of $V$ should be a martinagle.

Comment: It's seem you under the world of $W,$ $\dfrac{dV}{V} = \sigma_V\sigma_W\rho d t + \sigma_V(dW_V - \sigma_Wd t).$ Sorry, could you show detail, I may confused here.

Comment: I will add some details to the answer.

Comment: See added addendum.

Comment: thanks！ I get it. But how to obtain $W = \dfrac{P_X S}{P_Y}?$

Comment: Assume that $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are respectively the foreign and domestic money-market account, moreover, $S$ is the exchange rate from foreign to domestic. Then $P_X=e^{r_ft}$, $P_Y=e^{r_dt}$, and $dS = S((r_d-r_f)dt + \sigma_W dW_W)$. From here, you can find $W$.